# Powershell invoke-command access is denied error - not a double hop

Tags: powershell, access-denied, invoke-command

I am building a new network with Server 2016 and a handful of Windows 10 clients. I have run Enable-PSRemoting successfully on all the clients.  From the server I run:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer -Scriptblock {'test'}
```

which results in 
[computer] Connecting to remote server  failed with the following error message : Access is denied.
+ CategoryInfo: OpenError: (computer:string) [], PSRemotingTransportException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId: AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken

Because I am only having the remote computer process a string I believe this is not related to the common double hop issue I see in the forums.

I can also run WinRM successfully on the client machines:

```
Test-WSMan $computer
```

If anyone has insight into other causes of the access denied error I would greatly appreciate some ideas on where to look.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess it is a permission problem. Try to create `PsSession` object via

```
$s = New-PSSession -ComputerName "you_computer_name" -Credential(Get-Credential)
```

Call `Invoke-Command` with the beforehand created session object:

```
Invoke-Command -Session $s -ScriptBlock { Get-Service }
```

This should return a list of all services of remote machine.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks - this helped me find the issue.  I tried logging in with different user accounts and found one that had permission to run invoke-command.  I was trying to use an account without full permissions.

Answer (score 6):

You need to be in `Remote management users` group on target machine (if it's local account). This will be enough for Invoke-Command access